# bind enum to Combobox On CUSTOM CONTROL

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

I have a Custom control in WPF and I need to bind a comboBox on it to an enum I wrote,

searching on the web I found that this is the way to go:

```
<ObjectDataProvider
    MethodName="GetDict"
    ObjectType="{x:Type App:EnumDescriptionValueDict}"
    x:Key="EnumDescriptionDict">
  <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    <x:Type TypeName="App:Transmission"></x:Type>
  </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>

<ComboBox
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumDescriptionDict}}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Key"
      SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
```

but my control XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControlFoo.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="799" Height="107">
```

so I don't find a place to insert the **ObjectDataProvider** XAML

Thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: Use the <UserControl.Resources> area to define it in.

Comment: <UserControl.Resources><ObjectDataProvider ...></UserControl.Resources>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Resources as suggested in comments.

full XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControlFoo.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:App="myNamespaceWhereTheEnumIsLocated"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="799" Height="107">
<UserControl.Resources>
<ObjectDataProvider
    MethodName="GetDict"
    ObjectType="{x:Type App:EnumDescriptionValueDict}"
    x:Key="EnumDescriptionDict">
  <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    <x:Type TypeName="App:Transmission"></x:Type>
  </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ComboBox
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumDescriptionDict}}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Key"
      SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: And just to add to @Mat answer, `App:` is the namespace where you public enum is located.